# Store HTML List Into Data Attribute and Export to CSV

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a situation where I want to store HTML List data into an HTML data attribute as an array. and then export all data to a csv file.

HTML markup:

```
<ul class="unordered-list">                                 
    <li class="list-item"> 
        list item 1
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"> 
        list item 2
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"> 
        list item 3
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"> 
        list item's description
    </li>
    <li class="list-item"> 
        list item 5, this is list.
    </li>
</ul>
```

Button HTML to store data attribute:

```
<button class='import-list btn btn-success' data-title='" + title + "' data-desc='" + desc + "'>Export</button>
```

JavaScipt/jQuery code:

```
var desc = new Array(); 

 $(".unordered-list").find('.list-item').each(function(){
        var elem = $(this).text().trim();
        desc.push(elem);
    });

    $(".import-list").on("click", function(){

        var listArray = $(this).attr('data-desc');

        const replacer = (key, value) => value === null ? '' : value.replace(/\\/g, ''); // specify how you want to handle null values here
        const header = Object.keys(listArray[0]);
        let csv = listArray.map(row => header.map(fieldName => JSON.stringify(row[fieldName], replacer)).join(','));
        csv.unshift(header.join(',').replace(/\b\w/g, l => l.toUpperCase()));
        csv = csv.join('\r\n');

        var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');
        hiddenElement.href = 'data:text/csv;charset=utf-8,%EF%BB%BF' + encodeURI(csv);
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = 'export.csv';
        hiddenElement.click();
    });
```

This works, but the problem is: when I export it as CSV the `data-desc` values go to different cells or in a single cell but unable to identify them as an array because some strings also have comma inside.

All I want is,

1. when export it as CSV each custom data attribute should go to different cells.
2. `data-desc` value also as an array in a single cell.